# Why use the fictional name APF for the police force in True Detective Season 4?

Tags: true-detective

In Season 4 of *True Detective* (*Night Country*), Danvers and her colleagues work for the "APF", which I assume stands for Alaska Police Force.  As far as I can tell, there is no law enforcement agency by that name in real life.  Why did the creators and writers choose to use a fictional name, rather than the name of a real-life agency?

Navarro is depicted as an officer of the [Alaska State Troopers (AST)](https://dps.alaska.gov/AST/Home), which does exist in real life, and she is shown wearing what appears to be an authentic AST uniform (or very close facsimile).  In fact, in real life, it looks like major crime investigations in rural Alaska would be handled by the [Alaska Bureau of Investigations (ABI)](https://dps.alaska.gov/AST/ABI/Home), a division of the AST.  So it would have made sense to portray Danvers and company as ABI detectives.

In all the previous seasons, the main detective characters have been with real-life agencies (Louisiana State Police, California Highway Patrol, Ventura County Sheriff Department, Arkansas State Police).  The one obvious exception was the Vinci Police Department, since Vinci itself is fictional.

One guess is that the show is going to portray the APF in a negative light (corrupt, incompetent, etc), and if the showrunners had used the name ABI, they might not have been able to get the cooperation of AST/ABI in filming the show.  But that issue doesn't seem to have stopped them before - the portrayals of the police agencies in previous seasons have certainly not been especially positive.

Comment: TV shows often use fictional organisations so that you don't get people pointing out that "*such-and-such couldn't happen because XYZ has a policy against this"*

Comment: It's also the same reason why Euphoria isn't set in a specific city or why Sheldon Cooper doesn't have actual Aspergers.

Comment: @Valorum: Sure.  But as I mentioned, they used the names of real organizations in all the past seasons.  (And in Season 1, for instance, I'm pretty sure the real Louisiana State Police has policies against practically every single thing that Hart and Cohle did.)  Those issues apparently didn't bother them before, so I'm wondering what's different now.

Comment: @Valorum: And even within Season 4, they use the name and uniforms of the real Alaska State Troopers for Navarro's agency.

Comment: There is a "***[Airport Police and Fire](https://dot.alaska.gov/anc/business/policefire/index.shtml)***" (*Welcome to Airport Police and Fire. The Airport Police and Fire Department is responsible for ensuring around-the-clock police, fire, and first responder emergency medical services at Ted Stevens Anchorage International Airport*) that could stand for your "*APF*". As I haven't seen the show, I can't tell about this information reliability though...

Comment: @OldPadawan: Thanks for the guess, but no, the show has nothing to do with airports or firefighting, and it isn't set in Anchorage.  The APF in the show is a statewide police agency that's investigating a multiple murder in a remote Alaska town.  It would fit the Alaska Bureau of Investigation perfectly.